# How can I proof this sentence is true?

Tags: calculus

Let  $f\colon \Bbb R→\Bbb R$  be continuous, and differentiable at every point $x∈\Bbb R−\{c\}$  for some $c∈\Bbb R$.

If $\lim_{x\to c}f'(x)$ exists, then $f$ is differentiable at $x=c$ with $f'(c)=\lim_{x\to c}f'(x)$.

I want to know how to prove that the sentence above is true.

Answer (score 1):

By mean value theorem, for all $x \neq c$, it exists $a_x \in (x,c)$ such that

$$\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c} = f^\prime(a_x)$$ therefore if you denote $\lim\limits_{x \to c} f^\prime(x) =C$, you can prove that 
$$\lim\limits_{x \to c} \frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c} = C$$ with an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof. That allows to get the conclusion that $f^\prime(c)=C$.

Comment: Can you help me how to do that ϵ -δ proof too?

Comment: Can you write with $\epsilon$-$\delta$ the definition of $\lim\limits_{x \to c} f^\prime(x)=C$?

Comment: You don't need to go back to an $\epsilon-\delta$ proof. Just apply [composition of limits](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=composition+of+limits). You might also be interested by https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4517177